# The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection. - List

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

In my ASP.NET MVC4 project I got an entity that has a list of another entity.

```
public virtual IList<SupportTicketMessage> Messages { get; set; }
```

I can access the messages just fine however when I exit the dbcontext (exit using) I get the error:

*The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.*

I perfectly understand why I get the error but I'm wondering how I should deal with it? How can I access the messages when I'm not in the dbcontext anymore?

Comment: I guess you has `Lazy Loading` set to `true`. Try eager loading (with `Include("NavigationCollectionPropertyName")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include them in your original query. You can do this using `Include`:

```
List<Item> items;
using (var context = new YourContext())
{
    items = context.Items.Include(x => x.Messages).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Lazy Loading`, which uses your already disposed `DbContext`.
You need to turn off `Lazy Loading`, or just use `Eager Loading` for specific condition:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public virtual IList<SupportTicketMessage> Messages { get; set; }
}

var entry = db.Set<SomeClass>().Include("Messages").Single(t => t.ID = 1);
```